# PictureBox remains drawn in old position when movng to newer position

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, picturebox

I'm learning C# using the Head First C# book. In the first lab when building the Greyhound Racing game, I've encountered some behavior and I'm not understanding why my code is rendering the way it is. Upon the first click of the Race button, the horses race to the end of the track, yet they are rendered such that they each create a trail of previous images behind them until they reach the end of the track whereupon the preceding images finally vanish. Upon subsequent clicks of the Race button, the same thing occurs but it also fails to wipe the PictureBox for each dog from the finish line until the current race is complete.
[image]

Here's a short 19 second video that demonstrates what I mean: [Example of trailing images](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiXJqp264fs)

Why do the dogs 'trail' during the race, and why do they not vanish from the finish line upon being rendered at the start again until the completion of the next following race? I would think that when the dogs are repositioned in `TakeStartingPosition()` they would be moved, not redrawn. Same with the `Run()`, I would think each new position is a move and not a redraw yet it appears to be redrawing the image at each movement step and not wiping the old until the very end of the race. What am I doing incorrectly?

**Greyhound.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace RaceTrackSimulator
{
    class Greyhound
    {
        public int StartingPosition;
        public int RacetrackLength;
        public PictureBox MyPictureBox = null;
        public int Location = 0;
        public Random Randomizer;

        public bool Run()
        {
            // Move forward either 1, 2, 3 or 4 spaces at random
            int moveSpaces = Randomizer.Next(1, 4);


            // Update the position of my Picturebox on the form like this:
            //  MyPictureBox.Left = StartingPosition + Location;
            MyPictureBox.Left = StartingPosition + Location;

            // Return true if I won the race
            if (Location >= RacetrackLength)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Location += moveSpaces;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void TakeStartingPosition()
        {
            // Reset my location to 0 and my PictureBox to starting position
            Location = 0;
            MyPictureBox.Left = StartingPosition;

        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RaceTrackSimulator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Greyhound[] Dogs;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Random MyRandomizer = new Random();

            // Initialize Dogs
            Dogs = new Greyhound[4];

            Dogs[0] = new Greyhound()
            {
                MyPictureBox = pictureBox2,
                StartingPosition = racetrackPictureBox.Left,
                RacetrackLength = racetrackPictureBox.Width - pictureBox2.Width,
                Randomizer = MyRandomizer
            };

            Dogs[1] = new Greyhound()
            {
                MyPictureBox = pictureBox3,
                StartingPosition = racetrackPictureBox.Left,
                RacetrackLength = racetrackPictureBox.Width - pictureBox3.Width,
                Randomizer = MyRandomizer
            };

            Dogs[2] = new Greyhound()
            {
                MyPictureBox = pictureBox4,
                StartingPosition = racetrackPictureBox.Left,
                RacetrackLength = racetrackPictureBox.Width - pictureBox4.Width,
                Randomizer = MyRandomizer
            };

            Dogs[3] = new Greyhound()
            {
                MyPictureBox = pictureBox5,
                StartingPosition = racetrackPictureBox.Left,
                RacetrackLength = racetrackPictureBox.Width - pictureBox5.Width,
                Randomizer = MyRandomizer
            };
        }

        private void raceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool winner = false;
            int winningDog = 0;

            for (int eachDog = 0; eachDog < Dogs.Length; eachDog++)
            {
                Dogs[eachDog].TakeStartingPosition();
            }

            while (!winner)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    if (Dogs[i].Run())
                    {
                        winner = true;
                        winningDog = i+1;
                    }
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Winning Dog is #" + winningDog);
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
namespace RaceTrackSimulator
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.pictureBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.racetrackPictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox5 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.raceButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.racetrackPictureBox)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox5)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox2
            // 
            this.pictureBox2.Image = global::RaceTrackSimulator.Properties.Resources.dog;
            this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 22);
            this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
            this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 20);
            this.pictureBox2.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // racetrackPictureBox
            // 
            this.racetrackPictureBox.Image = global::RaceTrackSimulator.Properties.Resources.racetrack;
            this.racetrackPictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 12);
            this.racetrackPictureBox.Name = "racetrackPictureBox";
            this.racetrackPictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 200);
            this.racetrackPictureBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.racetrackPictureBox.TabIndex = 0;
            this.racetrackPictureBox.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox3
            // 
            this.pictureBox3.Image = global::RaceTrackSimulator.Properties.Resources.dog;
            this.pictureBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 74);
            this.pictureBox3.Name = "pictureBox3";
            this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 20);
            this.pictureBox3.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.pictureBox3.TabIndex = 3;
            this.pictureBox3.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox4
            // 
            this.pictureBox4.Image = global::RaceTrackSimulator.Properties.Resources.dog;
            this.pictureBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 126);
            this.pictureBox4.Name = "pictureBox4";
            this.pictureBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 20);
            this.pictureBox4.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.pictureBox4.TabIndex = 4;
            this.pictureBox4.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox5
            // 
            this.pictureBox5.Image = global::RaceTrackSimulator.Properties.Resources.dog;
            this.pictureBox5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 178);
            this.pictureBox5.Name = "pictureBox5";
            this.pictureBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 20);
            this.pictureBox5.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.pictureBox5.TabIndex = 5;
            this.pictureBox5.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // raceButton
            // 
            this.raceButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(538, 377);
            this.raceButton.Name = "raceButton";
            this.raceButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.raceButton.TabIndex = 6;
            this.raceButton.Text = "RACE!";
            this.raceButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.raceButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.raceButton_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(625, 412);
            this.Controls.Add(this.raceButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.racetrackPictureBox);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.racetrackPictureBox)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox5)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox racetrackPictureBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button raceButton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a tight loop in the button click handler handler, which is monopolizing the main UI thread.  When the dog moves forward, it is up to the form to repaint itself to "erase" where the dog previously was.  Since the code is stuck in the loop, however, it cannot redraw itself.  Similarly, when the race is restarted, the dogs do not disappear from the finish line for the same reason.

One possible "quick fix" is to call `Application.DoEvents();` in the code to allow the form to update itself.  That would look like this:

```
    private void raceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool winner = false;
        int winningDog = 0;

        for (int eachDog = 0; eachDog < Dogs.Length; eachDog++)
        {
            Dogs[eachDog].TakeStartingPosition();
        }
        Application.DoEvents();

        while (!winner)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (Dogs[i].Run())
                {
                    winner = true;
                    winningDog = i+1;
                }
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Winning Dog is #" + winningDog);
    }
```

This, however, is simply a band-aid on top of the real problem:  **You shouldn't be monopolizing the main UI thread with a long running loop in the button click handler.**

One possible solution is reset the dogs in the button click handler, then start a **Timer**.  In the Tick() event of the Timer() you would call each dogs Run() method and check for a winner.  When the race has been won, turn the Timer back off.

Comment: Thanks. That was definitely the missing bit of knowledge I needed. I can start a timer to contain the race, and disable the Race button while the timer is ticking through the race.

Comment: Perfect.  The call to Sleep() shouldn't be necessary in the loop anymore, either.  You can adjust the speed of the dogs by changing the Interval() of the Timer.  DoEvents() is also no longer necessary once you've switched over to the Timer since normal messages (like painting) will get processed in-between the Tick() events.